# probability of three event

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

A questionnaire survey on the use of SNS was conducted for students at A University.  As a result,
 we got the following:

$55\%$ using Twitter ,

$53\%$ using Facebook ,

$20\%$ using Twitter and facebook both,

$19\%$ use both Facebook and
 Instagram.

$76\%$ use at least  Twitter
 and / or Instagram

$72\%$ use at least one of Facebook
 and Instagram

$49\%$ use only one of twitter ,facebook, or instagram
At this time, find the next
 ratio respectively.

$1$. Percentage of using both
 Twitter and Instagram

$2$. Percentage of using all
 of Twitter, Facebook and Instagram

$3$. Percentage of not using
 either Twitter, Facebook or Instagram

I was confused, for $P(T\cap F)=20\%$ does this also include $P(T\cap F \cap I )$ ?
for $P(F) $ only = $P(F\cap T)$, is it correct only facebook is $14\%$?
$P(F)=53\% - P(F\cap T) - P(F\cap I)=53\%-19\%-20\% =14\%$?

i could find $P(T \cup F) = P(T)+P(F)-P(T \cap  F)=55\% +53\%-20\%=88% $ is this right?
$P(T) =35$ but i dont know $P(T \cap I)$

P(F)=14

i manage to find :
$P(T \cap I) = 17 $ and $P(I)=38$ 
but when i count $P(T \cup F \cup I) = P(T)+P(F)+P(I)-P(T \cap F) - P(T \cap I) - Ｐ(I \cap F) + P(T \cap F \cap I) = $
$49=55+53+38-20-19-17 +P(T \cap F \cap I) $ 
$P(T \cap F \cap I)=-41$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may draw the Venn Diagram.

[image]

$ \begin{cases}
c+e+g+h=0.55 \\
b+e+f+h=0.53 \\
e+h=0.2 \\
f+h=0.19 \\
c+d+e+f+g+h=0.76 \\
b+d+e+f+g+h=0.72 \\
b+c+d=0.49 \\
a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h=1
\end{cases}$

and we want to find

1. $g+h=?$
2. $h=?$
3. $a=?$

We have $e=0.2-h$ and $f=0.19-h$. The system is equivalent to

$ \begin{cases}
e=0.2-h \\
f=0.19-h \\
c+g=0.35 \\
b=h+0.14 \\
c+d+g=0.37+h \\
b+d+g=0.33+h \\
b+c+d=0.49 \\
a+b+c+d+g=0.61+h
\end{cases}$

$ \begin{cases}
e=0.2-h \\
f=0.19-h \\
b=h+0.14 \\
c=0.35-g \\
d=0.02+h \\
d=0.19-g \\
c+d=0.35-h \\
a+d=0.12
\end{cases}$

So, $0.02+h=d=0.19-g $ and hence $g=0.17-h$

$0.35-h=c+d=0.35-(0.17-h)+0.02+h$

$h=0.05$.

$a=0.05$, $b=0.19$, $c=0.23$, $d=0.07$, $e=0.15$, $f=0.14$, $g=0.12$.

---

Your symbols are a bit confusing. $P(T\cup F\cup I)$ is not $0.49$

What we have is $P((T\setminus(F \cup I))\cup( F\setminus(T \cup I))\cup( I\setminus (F\cup T)))=0.49$.

Note that $P((T\setminus(F \cup I))\cup( F\setminus(T \cup I))\cup( I\setminus (F\cup T)))=P(T\setminus(F \cup I))+P(F\setminus(T \cup I))+P( I\setminus (F\cup T))$.

$P(T\setminus(F \cup I))=P(T)-P(F\cap T)-P(I \cap T)+P(T\cap F\cap I)$

We can also expand $P(F\setminus(T \cup I))$ and $P( I\setminus (F\cup T))$ and yield

\begin{align*}
&\;P((T\setminus(F \cup I))\cup( F\setminus(T \cup I))\cup( I\setminus (F\cup T)))\\
=&\;P(T)+P(F)+P(I)-2P(F\cap T)-2P(I \cap T)-2P(F \cap I)+3P(T\cap F\cap I)
\end{align*}

$\displaystyle 0.49=0.55+0.53+0.38-2(0.17)-2(0.19)-2(0.2)+3P(T\cap F\cap I)$

$P(T\cap F\cap I)=0.05$

Comment: really appreciate for your help to make me understand by drawing the figure !! is this problem can be solved by using this equation? $P(T \cup F \cup I) = P(T)+P(F)+P(I)-P(T \cap F) - P(T \cap I) - Ｐ(I \cap F) + P(T \cap F \cap I) $ ? or is it better to solve this problem in your way?

Comment: The problem is that we don't have $P(T\cup F\cup I)$.

Comment: @devss I have added a second method, without using the Venn Diagram.

Comment: thankyou so much for the help!! learn a lot from your post!

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

1. $P(T\cup F)+P(T\cap F)=P(T)+P(F)$
2. $P(T\cup F \cup I)=P(T)+P(F)+P(I)-P(T\cap F)-P(T\cap I)-P(I\cap F) + P(T\cap F \cap I)$
3. $P(\overline A) = 1 - P(A)$

Comment: is the probability twitter only also include $P(T\cap F)$ and $P(T \cap I)$?

Comment: i manage to find this but why this is negative? $P(T \cup F \cup I) = P(T)+P(F)+P(I)-P(T \cap F) - P(T \cap I) - Ｐ(I \cap F) + P(T \cap F \cap I) = $<br>
$49=55+53+38-20-19-17 +P(T \cap F \cap I) $ then
$P(T \cap F \cap I)=-41$

Comment: @devss because $P(T\cup F\cup I)$ is the probability that they use *at least one of* the three social media platforms, possibly multiple.  The value of $49\%$ in the problem however is not this, but is rather the probability that they use *exactly one* and *only* one social media platform.  That would be represented as $P((T\setminus (F\cup I)) \cup (F\setminus (T\cup I))\cup (I\setminus(T\cup F)))$ or other equivalents.

Comment: @devss You can use Venn diagrams, for deriving them. They are very useful in such cases